# Objectify Filter by Ref

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

I have a m-n relationship with Objectify, and I want to get 1 side of the relation.

I was trying to solve it with this query:

```
        Query query = ofy().load().type(Person.class);
        query.filter("position", ceo);
        return query.list();
```

To return a list of CEOs.
Position is a Ref< Position>.

I have tried:

```
query.filter("position", Ref.create(ceo));
query.filter("position", Key.create(ceo));
query.filter("position", ceo.key);
```

But nothing, does anyone knows how to do this?

---

EDIT: It was an Index problem. Sorry!

Comment: your "edit" pointed me in the right direction: https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Concepts#Indexes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
query = query.filter("position", ceo);
```

All Objectify command objects are immutable.